# ios app rejected, they say ipV6 problems; need help identifying the issue

Tags: ios, ipv6

Apple rejected my app today, this is what they sent to me:

"We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Next Steps

Please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure it will launch without crashing."

```
Incident Identifier: D1567D74-C4CB-464D-945C-5510E22A5E67
CrashReporter Key:   45e776ed0586d581aba248bf3f23eaf42a231f2c
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             MyAppiOS [1576]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/79C23898-D672-4AA6-BD4C-6EBAE68918FF/xxxxxx.app/xxxxxxiOS
Identifier:          it.xxxxx.xxxxxx
Version:             1.3 (1.3)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-07-31 13:37:27.27 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-07-31 13:37:27.27 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.3 (13G34)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018071c11c 0x180700000 + 114972
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e8ef8 0x1807e4000 + 20216
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018068ddc8 0x18062c000 + 400840
3   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100ef7b0c 0x10007c000 + 15186700
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001807e194c 0x1807dc000 + 22860
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e8ef8 0x1807e4000 + 20216
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018068ddc8 0x18062c000 + 400840
7   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fe8988 0x10007c000 + 16173448
8   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100ef805c 0x10007c000 + 15188060
9   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100ef7518 0x10007c000 + 15185176
10  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100ef6354 0x10007c000 + 15180628
11  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100eef2d0 0x10007c000 + 15151824
12  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010045d178 0x10007c000 + 4067704
13  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010054cf44 0x10007c000 + 5050180
14  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010054c998 0x10007c000 + 5048728
15  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100a58094 0x10007c000 + 10338452
16  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010095fd8c 0x10007c000 + 9321868
17  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010095f57c 0x10007c000 + 9319804
18  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001002a9cf4 0x10007c000 + 2284788
19  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010043d364 0x10007c000 + 3937124
20  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100f06bf4 0x10007c000 + 15248372
21  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100f6a974 0x10007c000 + 15657332
22  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100eb0c34 0x10007c000 + 14896180
23  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100eb406c 0x10007c000 + 14909548
24  UIKit                           0x0000000185d4e9c0 0x185cc4000 + 567744
25  UIKit                           0x0000000185f7e184 0x185cc4000 + 2859396
26  UIKit                           0x0000000185f825f0 0x185cc4000 + 2876912
27  UIKit                           0x0000000185f7f764 0x185cc4000 + 2864996
28  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001825237ac 0x1824fc000 + 161708
29  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000182523618 0x1824fc000 + 161304
30  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001825239c8 0x1824fc000 + 162248
31  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180b3909c 0x180a58000 + 921756
32  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180b38b30 0x180a58000 + 920368
33  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180b36830 0x180a58000 + 911408
34  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a60c50 0x180a58000 + 35920
35  UIKit                           0x0000000185d4794c 0x185cc4000 + 538956
36  UIKit                           0x0000000185d42088 0x185cc4000 + 516232
37  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001002e48fc 0x10007c000 + 2525436
38  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010031bc8c 0x10007c000 + 2751628
39  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001002a9c28 0x10007c000 + 2284584
40  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010043d364 0x10007c000 + 3937124
41  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100f06bf4 0x10007c000 + 15248372
42  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100f6a974 0x10007c000 + 15657332
43  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100f6f1fc 0x10007c000 + 15675900
44  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100ffa6f4 0x10007c000 + 16246516
45  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100ec5050 0x10007c000 + 14979152
46  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001805fe8b8 0x1805fc000 + 10424

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018071cb48 0x180700000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e5530 0x1807e4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e5020 0x1807e4000 + 4128

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018071d4d8 0x180700000 + 120024
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001805e07d8 0x1805cc000 + 83928
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001805cf648 0x1805cc000 + 13896

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018071cb48 0x180700000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e5530 0x1807e4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e5020 0x1807e4000 + 4128

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018071c41c 0x180700000 + 115740
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018063922c 0x18062c000 + 53804
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001801b13b4 0x18016c000 + 283572
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018477a698 0x1841f8000 + 5777048
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018477a348 0x1841f8000 + 5776200
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018477cae0 0x1841f8000 + 5786336
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018477ca70 0x1841f8000 + 5786224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e7b28 0x1807e4000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e7a8c 0x1807e4000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e5028 0x1807e4000 + 4136

Thread 5 name:  WebThread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180700fd8 0x180700000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180700e54 0x180700000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180b38c60 0x180a58000 + 920672
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180b36964 0x180a58000 + 911716
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a60c50 0x180a58000 + 35920
5   WebCore                         0x0000000184a46108 0x1849d0000 + 483592
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e7b28 0x1807e4000 + 15144
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e7a8c 0x1807e4000 + 14988
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e5028 0x1807e4000 + 4136

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180701014 0x180700000 + 4116
1   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fd4784 0x10007c000 + 16091012
2   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100f34c20 0x10007c000 + 15436832
3   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fb62dc 0x10007c000 + 15966940
4   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fd517c 0x10007c000 + 16093564
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e7b28 0x1807e4000 + 15144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e7a8c 0x1807e4000 + 14988
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e5028 0x1807e4000 + 4136

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018071cb48 0x180700000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e5530 0x1807e4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e5020 0x1807e4000 + 4128

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018071bf24 0x180700000 + 114468
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e6ce8 0x1807e4000 + 11496
2   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fbadc0 0x10007c000 + 15986112
3   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fc69c4 0x10007c000 + 16034244
4   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fb1d98 0x10007c000 + 15949208
5   MyAppiOS                    0x00000001003e9910 0x10007c000 + 3594512
6   MyAppiOS                    0x000000010054c7e4 0x10007c000 + 5048292
7   MyAppiOS                    0x000000010054c88c 0x10007c000 + 5048460
8   MyAppiOS                    0x000000010054c13c 0x10007c000 + 5046588
9   MyAppiOS                    0x000000010054ab78 0x10007c000 + 5041016
10  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010043d364 0x10007c000 + 3937124
11  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100f06bf4 0x10007c000 + 15248372
12  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100f6a974 0x10007c000 + 15657332
13  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fb6344 0x10007c000 + 15967044
14  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fd517c 0x10007c000 + 16093564
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e7b28 0x1807e4000 + 15144
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e7a8c 0x1807e4000 + 14988
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e5028 0x1807e4000 + 4136

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018071bf24 0x180700000 + 114468
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e6ce8 0x1807e4000 + 11496
2   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fbadc0 0x10007c000 + 15986112
3   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fc69c4 0x10007c000 + 16034244
4   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100f621f4 0x10007c000 + 15622644
5   MyAppiOS                    0x00000001003e8318 0x10007c000 + 3588888
6   MyAppiOS                    0x000000010054a3dc 0x10007c000 + 5039068
7   MyAppiOS                    0x00000001003b5698 0x10007c000 + 3380888
8   MyAppiOS                    0x00000001003b5460 0x10007c000 + 3380320
9   MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100601e80 0x10007c000 + 5791360
10  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100601d18 0x10007c000 + 5791000
11  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100601c3c 0x10007c000 + 5790780
12  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100e60788 0x10007c000 + 14567304
13  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010054ab78 0x10007c000 + 5041016
14  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010043d364 0x10007c000 + 3937124
15  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100f06bf4 0x10007c000 + 15248372
16  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100f6a974 0x10007c000 + 15657332
17  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fb6344 0x10007c000 + 15967044
18  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000100fd517c 0x10007c000 + 16093564
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e7b28 0x1807e4000 + 15144
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e7a8c 0x1807e4000 + 14988
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807e5028 0x1807e4000 + 4136

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000180748664
    x4: 0x0000000000000043   x5: 0x0000000000000041   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000136790000  x11: 0x0000000000003fff
   x12: 0x000000013678c000  x13: 0x0000000000003fff  x14: 0xffffffffffffc000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019ede5000  x21: 0x0000000101489d45  x22: 0x0000000101489e0c  x23: 0x4900c357811c5df7
   x24: 0x000000016fd7fd28  x25: 0x0000000101489dbf  x26: 0x0000000137916b60  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x000000013683ae00  fp: 0x000000016fd7fcc0   lr: 0x00000001807e8ef8
    sp: 0x000000016fd7fca0   pc: 0x000000018071c11c cpsr: 0x00000000
```

you can see complete log file they sent to me [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4aGvecMFcFWdHM3M1g2YWV3UVU)

Many thanks for your interest to my question

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log.

Comment: How to symbolicate crash log ?

Comment: this is fine? [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4aGvecMFcFWd3Jxa3BpQWhKc0E)